# How to put my text under my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, formatting, navbar

Okay so I have a nav bar for my website and I have never ran into this issue. All my text goes right behind my nav bar and not under. It could be because my navbar is made to auto adjust for mobile screens.

```
<body>
             <nav>
                 <h1 class="brand"><a href="#">CHS Robotics</a></h1>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Club Info</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Positions</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <div style="clear: both"></div>
             </nav>
                  <div class="responsive-bar">
                  <h3 class="brand"><a href="#">CHS Robotics</a></h3>
                  <h4 class="menu">Menu</h4>
                  <div style="clear: both"></div>
                  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                         $(document).ready(function(){
                            $(".menu").click(function(){
                                $("nav").slideToggle(500);
                            })


                         }) 
               <h1 class="about">About CHS Robotics</h1>
```

More info: Cyrusmusic101.github.io

Comment: You're missing a closing </div> for your .responsive-bar. This is placing your h1 text in the header, or is it suppose to be apart of the menu?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you clear your cache, since there's nothing wrong with the code and it seems perfectly fine when I access the link.
(Also, if something were wrong it would probably be the CSS, so it'd be useful to also post it).